# JavaFX Rubik Cube - cubie selection

Tags: java, javafx, observablelist, javafx-3d, rubiks-cube

I am trying to build a Rubiks Cube from scratch as my first `real` app using JavaFx. In the `Moves` class Im selecting Boxes from ObservableList based on position. The problem is that the Box.getTranslate dosent update so  when I try to move the front and the left faces successively the Boxes selected by both are always moved resulting in.. chaos. How could I re-write this so that the Move methods correctly select the boxes to move? Here is the code, work in progress.

Main

```
package ro.adrianpush;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Box;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class Main extends Application {

    private static final int WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 600;
    final Group root = new Group();


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        Camera camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
        camera.translateXProperty().setValue(-200);
        camera.translateYProperty().setValue(0);
        camera.translateZProperty().set(-500);

        AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();

        Rubik rubik = new Rubik();
        ObservableList<Box> boxArrayList = rubik.getBoxArrayList();

        for (Box box: boxArrayList
        ) {
                pane.getChildren().addAll(box);
        }

        primaryStage.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
            switch (event.getCode()){
                case E:
                    Moves.rotateFront(boxArrayList, "clockwise");
                    break;
                case Q:
                    Moves.rotateFront(boxArrayList, "counterclockwise");
                    break;
                case A:
                    Moves.rotateLeft(boxArrayList, "clockwise");
                    break;
                case D:
                    Moves.rotateLeft(boxArrayList, "counterclockwise");
                    break;

            }
        });

        root.getChildren().add(pane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, WIDTH, HEIGHT, true);
        scene.setCamera(camera);
        scene.setFill(Color.ROYALBLUE);
        primaryStage.setTitle("The game nobody wants to play");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


}
```

Rubik

```
package ro.adrianpush;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.shape.Box;


public class Rubik {

    private ObservableList<Box> boxArrayList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    public Rubik(){

        for(int i = 1; i < 4; i+=1){
            for( int j = 1; j < 4; j++){
                for(int k = 1; k < 4; k++){

                    Box box = new Box(100,100,100);
                    box.setTranslateX(i*100);
                    box.setTranslateY(j*100);
                    box.setTranslateZ(k*100);
                    boxArrayList.add(box);
                }
            }
        }

    }



    public ObservableList<Box> getBoxArrayList() {
        return boxArrayList;
    }


}
```

Moves

```
package ro.adrianpush;


import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.shape.Box;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;

public class Moves {

    public static void rotateFront(ObservableList<Box> boxArrayList, String direction) {

        for (Box box: boxArrayList
             ) {

            if(box.getTranslateZ() == 100){
                Rotate rotate = new Rotate();
                rotate.setAxis(Rotate.Z_AXIS);
                if(direction == "clockwise"){
                    rotate.setAngle(5);
                } else if (direction == "counterclockwise"){
                    rotate.setAngle(-5);
                }

                if(box.getTranslateX() == 100){
                    rotate.setPivotX(100);
                }  if (box.getTranslateX() == 300){
                    rotate.setPivotX(-100);
                }  if(box.getTranslateY() == 100){
                    rotate.setPivotY(100);
                }  if(box.getTranslateY() == 300){
                    rotate.setPivotY(-100);
                }

                box.getTransforms().add(rotate);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void rotateBack(ObservableList<Box> boxArrayList, String direction) {

        for (Box box: boxArrayList
        ) {

            if(box.getTranslateZ() == 300){
                Rotate rotate = new Rotate();

                if(direction == "clockwise"){
                    rotate.setAngle(5);
                } else if (direction == "counterclockwise"){
                    rotate.setAngle(-5);
                }

                if(box.getTranslateX() == 100){
                    rotate.setPivotX(100);
                }  if (box.getTranslateX() == 300){
                    rotate.setPivotX(-100);
                }  if(box.getTranslateY() == 100){
                    rotate.setPivotY(100);
                }  if(box.getTranslateY() == 300){
                    rotate.setPivotY(-100);
                }

                box.getTransforms().add(rotate);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void rotateLeft(ObservableList<Box> boxArrayList, String direction) {

        for (Box box: boxArrayList
        ) {

            if(box.getTranslateX() == 100){
                Rotate rotate = new Rotate();
                rotate.setAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);

                if(direction == "clockwise"){
                    rotate.setAngle(5);
                } else if (direction == "counterclockwise"){
                    rotate.setAngle(-5);
                }

                if(box.getTranslateY() == 100){
                    rotate.setPivotY(100);
                }  if (box.getTranslateY() == 300){
                    rotate.setPivotY(-100);
                }  if(box.getTranslateZ() == 100){
                    rotate.setPivotZ(100);
                }  if(box.getTranslateZ() == 300){
                    rotate.setPivotZ(-100);
                }

                box.getTransforms().add(rotate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this](http://jperedadnr.blogspot.com/2014/04/rubikfx-solving-rubiks-cube-with-javafx.html) take on the task.

Comment: Your `for` loops are not formatted properly, the `(` should be on the same line and usually the `{` is too.

Comment: As @user1803551 mentioned, that blog post is a good way to start. I discussed about the use of `prepend` transform instead of `add`. See also the projects [LiteRubikFX](https://github.com/jperedadnr/LiteRubikFX) and [RubikFX](https://github.com/jperedadnr/RubikFX), or even [Rubiks-cube](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/rubiks-cube) on mobile. See [this](https://gist.github.com/jperedadnr/28534fcdce605b75382b) for a lighter version of the cube.